# Culture building destroyed (not disabled) if I build one as different culture?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

My understanding was that when a character of a different culture takes over a barony, the cultural building of the previous culture is disabled.

This happened in my situation, I was Dutch culture with a Large Goedendag Militia Quarters (3rd tier cultural building). My inheritor was Italian culture, so that building disappeared and I was presented with the option of build the tier 1 Italian cultural building. I had done so, and later on I managed to restore Dutch culture to my heirs. The Godendag quarters were wiped out, I had to start at tier 1 again.

My question is two-fold:

- Am I right in my original understanding? If I change culture and don't build a new cultural building, will it the original building restored if I switch back to my original culture?
- Since I build a new building, is what I experienced a bug, or working as designed? (in case of bug, my current build is 2.1.4 checksum XQSJ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No in both cases. When a castle gets a ruler with a new culture, then culture-specific buildings are lost forever, you should start anew. And it's not a bug.

Comment: Further play seems to confirm what you say.